# Cleanup 2013: It's time to clearly identify community consensus

Tags: discussion, site-policies, site-faq

On meta we have a tag to denote frequently asked questions, it is the moderator only bright red tag known as [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). This tag provides us the opportunity to group together our agreed community consensuses, allowing us easy access to reference them and an easy way to point new users trying to learn how we work to the many hours of discussion that resulted in us working that way in the first place.

Here is some past reading for some background on where this post is coming from:

- [What questions should be in our meta FAQ?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5165/52800)
- [Update the FAQ tag or create a new tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7759/52800)

Currently, the FAQ tag is underused, containing only nine questions. These are nine very good questions and provide a very good basis to some of the more obvious questions, even though a couple of them are edge cases.

The FAQ tag is linked to directly from the help page, and while the help page is very good, it doesn't detail how or why we do many of the things we do. I once wrote how perplexing it was trying to work out how Arqade works, shortly after starting. I know I'm not alone in these thoughts because many other new users have experienced the same issues.

The purpose of this post is to form community consensus on what exactly should be included and should be approached as follows:

- Upvote the question if you think grouping all of our community agreed policies should be tagged together to make them easier to find.
- Downvote the question if you don't think grouping all of our community agreed policies should be tagged together.
- Post answers detailing the questions on meta you think should be included under this tag, whether that tag be [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) or [site-policies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-policies) or a new tag altogether. Detail in your answer why you think the question/answer linked is worthy of inclusion so everybody else can understand.
- Vote on the answers to agree or disagree that you think that question should be officially backed and enforced as site policy.

Comment: Do we have a hard limit of answer score (total up - total down) makes community consensus enough so that mods can start faq'ing?

Comment: I think a deadline/time limit is probably a better way of doing it - probably a week from now, to give everybody a fair chance to see the post and contribute - then probably everything with a positive overall score depending on the number of proposals put forward

Comment: Sounds good (15 chars)

Answer (score 23):

[A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote. Please don't use it as one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one)

This question and answers further detail downvoting, closing, question protecting and flagging.

Comment: This question will need to be updated to reflect the current changes to the close vote reasons: [Closing changes: \[on hold\], unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/162827)

Answer (score 19):

[Please, please, please, don't edit out spam links](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/please-please-please-dont-edit-out-spam-links)

This question details how to deal with spam posts on the site.

Comment: This is especially pertinent after the new recent functionality which hides spam links once they're deleted by the system as a result of spam flags

Answer (score 15):

[What is an audiovisual artifact?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/what-is-an-audiovisual-artifact)

This question and answers detail what is required for [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) to be acceptable.

Answer (score 14):

[When does a question "support piracy and pirated games"?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/when-does-a-question-support-piracy-and-pirated-games)

This question and answers detail what the community considers to support piracy.

Answer (score 11):

[Are trivial questions allowed on the site?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7570/are-trivial-questions-allowed-on-the-site)

This question and accepted answer reflect the community's opinion on trivial questions.

Answer (score 11):

[When is a game publicly available?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available)

This question and answers reflect the community's opinion on when a game in development is no longer considered off-topic.

Answer (score 11):

[What do we do with questions about games that can no longer be played?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/what-do-we-do-with-questions-about-games-that-can-no-longer-be-played)

This question and answers detail how we handle games that are no longer available.

Answer (score 10):

[Let's be nice to each other](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/lets-be-nice-to-each-other)

Details the ideal sentiment of the site and the community we're trying to build.

Answer (score 9):

[Please don't misuse the voting system](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system)

This question details voting practices and the answers contain more information and a great guide on voting.

Answer (score 8):

[Should lore questions as an entire category be banned?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7696/52800)

This question and associated answers detail the community's opinion on lore questions and concludes that lore questions are on topic on Arqade.

Answer (score 8):

[How do we handle duplicate answers?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/how-do-we-handle-duplicate-answers)

This question and answers detail the policy on duplicate answers, which is to delete exact duplicates.

Answer (score 8):

[Edit wars are bad. Don't encourage or participate in them](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/edit-wars-are-bad-dont-encourage-or-participate-in-them)

Useful for people who are just coming into the edit rep threshold.

Comment: Useful for everyone.  No matter how much rep you have, you can always edit your own posts.

Answer (score 7):

[When is non-game-specific still on-topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/when-is-non-game-specific-still-on-topic)

This question and answers reflect the community's opinion on questions about non-game-specific programs.

Answer (score 7):

[Should we reopen questions being closed for 'unreleased game' after the game is released?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/should-we-reopen-question-being-closed-for-unreleased-game-after-the-game-is-r)

This question and answers go into detail about question parking and reopening unreleased questions.

Answer (score 7):

[Is "mod rec" really an umbrella category that we want to use? Or is it confusing the situation?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6828/4797)

Reflects community consensus regarding questions that are "mod recommendations", AKA "mod rec" (questions where mods are mentioned as possible or preferable solutions by the OP)

Quoting excerpts from the [current top-voted answer by agent86](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6830/4797):

> On our site, these questions take a form where a mod is generally a solution to a problem. Judge questions by the problem being posed instead of the presupposed answer.
>
> Recommending solutions from a large number of possibilities is the core of a wide swath of questions.

Comment: This is an important FAQ, but the title isn't terribly clear.

Answer (score 4):

[Should I approve suggested edits that I don't know if they are true?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6786/52800)

This question and associated answer detail approving suggested edits without prior knowledge or researching the amendment to ensure it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

[What's our procedure for asking about not-quite-legal games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4498/4797)

Reflects community consensus regarding questions about games in a legal gray area - e.g. fan-made ROM patches

Answer (score 3):

[Outdated Answers Due to Patches](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/946/outdated-answers-due-to-patches)

This question & associated answer show how to retroactively deal with questions that may be outdated or obsolete.

Comment: The top-voted answer in that 2010 meta post seems to be contradictory to community consensus in these more recent meta posts: [(2012) Can we stop closing questions that have become obsolete as “Too Localized”?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5282/4797) and [(2013) What should be done with out of version questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5727/4797)

Comment: I've added "What should be done with out of version questions?" as another answer here:  http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7883/4797

Answer (score 3):

[About the violence inherent in Stack Exchange: freedom of speech](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7918/52800)

This post reflects the policy on editing and moderating content on the site.

Comment: It's a valuable meta post, but I feel like the joke nature of the question and title hurt it.

Comment: I agree, it would need... something doing to it, before being added to the FAQ

Answer (score 2):

[Are questions about patch notes too localized?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/are-questions-about-patch-notes-too-localized)

This question and answers detail "patch note" questions and conclude that questions should be about a part of game not about recent changes to that part of the game.

Answer (score 2):

[Non-gaming gaming console questions -- allowed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/non-gaming-gaming-console-questions-allowed)

This question and answers conclude that all console questions are on topic whether or not they are about gaming.

Answer (score 2):

[What's the official stance on hacked/modded consoles?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/258/4797)

Reflects community consensus regarding questions about hacked/modded consoles

Answer (score 2):

[Please fill in the alt text for images on this site](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7470/please-fill-in-the-alt-text-for-images-on-this-site)

This question deals with accessibility of the site, specifically with filling in image alternate text so screen readers can give a meaningful description of the image. There are still plenty of images posted every day with 'Enter image description here'.

We should be proactively enforcing this, instead of retroactively editing them later.

Comment: HOW EVERYTHING OUT

Comment: God. Remember the sequel?

Comment: HOW EVERYTHING OUT 2: THE HOWENING

Answer (score 2):

- [Are questions about unreleased consoles on topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/are-questions-about-unreleased-consoles-on-topic)

Similar to questions about unreleased games, unreleased consoles are also off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

[Could someone explain this joke to me?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/could-someone-explain-this-joke-to-me)

This question and answer go into detail about gaming memes and jokes. This post determines that questions should only be asked about `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.` and as such, these types of questions are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

[What should be done with questions asking for game recommendations?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations)

Now we know what should be done - get rid of them! It essentially says this in the FAQ but a bit of reiteration never hurts.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it bad practice to upvote to help out?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5648/is-it-bad-practice-to-upvote-to-help-out)

This question and answers detail why upvoting to help out is a bad practice.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7860/51318 is probably a better option, if both are not desired.

Answer (score 0):

[Should answers on questions that ask for spoiler information be put in spoiler markup or not?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7128/4797)

This question reflects community consensus on which answers (or answer parts) should be put in spoiler markup or not. It would help guide users on the usage of spoiler markup on answers, and would help avoid edit wars about an answer's spoiler markup.

Answer (score -1):

[What's bad in helping a person who bought legal version of a game move their save files from cracked copy?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7203/whats-bad-in-helping-a-person-who-bought-legal-version-of-a-game-move-their-sav/7205#7205)

This question and answer deal with why we don't support blatant piracy, (in any way, shape or form).

Answer (score -1):

[How should I write tag wikis?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7837/52800)

This question details the (soon to be?) community agreed tag wiki format which should be used when creating or editing tag wikis.

Answer (score -2):

[What should be done with out of version questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5727/4797)

This question reflects community consensus regarding questions that may be considered outdated or obsolete.

Note: The consensus in this 2013 meta post seems to be contradictory to a [similar 2010 meta discussion (Outdated Answers Due to Patches)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7878/4797). I believe this should supersede that older meta post as it is more recent.

Answer (score -3):

[Is programming, in a game, on topic here?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7661/is-programming-in-a-game-on-topic-here)

This question and answers reflect the community's opinion on questions about programming in a game.

Comment: This doesn't come up often enough to be in the FAQ.

Comment: Perhaps [site-policies] then, as per the instructions in the question

Answer (score -5):

[Can better support be added for creating tables, for science?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/can-better-support-be-added-for-creating-tables-for-science)

There are a lot of answers where this method of embedding tables would be handy - I wish I'd known about it when I started out here!