# About the violence inherent in Stack Exchange: freedom of speech

Tags: support, moderation

<sub>Please print, tick what applies, sign, put on a wooden table, photograph and send by mail or fax. Attach an ID</sub>

**My**
❏ question 
❏ answer 
❏ post 
❏ tag 
❏ comment 
❏ chat 
❏ revision 
❏ message 
❏ formatting 
❏ spoiler box 
❏ gfycat 
❏ imgv 
❏ youtube 
❏ video 
❏ thumbnail 
❏ image 
❏ picture 
❏ link 
❏ photograph 
❏ of this form 
❏ clipart 
❏ mspaint 
❏ ART 
❏ fanfiction 
❏ astroturf 
❏ poem 
❏ ascii art 
❏ unicode art 
❏ emoji 
❏ avatar 
❏ username 
❏ about me box 
❏ insult 
❏ appellative 
❏ sentence 
❏ phrase 
❏ word 
❏ typo 
❏ vowel 
❏ consonant 
❏ punctuation 
❏ plenken 
❏ klempen 
❏ HTML comment 
❏ list 
❏ headcanon 
❏ deep lore 
❏ complaint form

**has/have been** 
❏ slightly 
❏ radically 
❏ completely 
❏ unceremoniously 
❏ hastily 
❏ meticulously 
❏ nastily 
❏ chastily 
❏ prudely 
❏ defiantly 
❏ automagically 
❏ definitely 
❏ repeatedly 
❏ maliciously

❏ censored 
❏ falsified 
❏ flagged 
❏ closed 
❏ deleted 
❏ moved 
❏ anonymized 
❏ reattributed 
❏ reordered 
❏ reorganized 
❏ redecorated 
❏ altered 
❏ neutered 
❏ delayed 
❏ prevented 
❏ protected 
❏ locked 
❏ annotated 
❏ declined 
❏ annihilated 
❏ deprecated 
❏ suspended 
❏ shadow- 
❏ banned 
❏ dezalgoified 
❏ zalgoified 
❏ HE COMES

**by a(n)**
❏ nazist 
❏ fascist 
❏ overzealous 
❏ misguided 
❏ malevolent 
❏ corrupt 
❏ violent 
❏ rude 
❏ power-tripping

❏ dude 
❏ bro 
❏ pegasister 
❏ moderator 
❏ 20k censor 
❏ 10k moderator 
❏ 3k closer 
❏ 2k editor 
❏ random person on the internet 
❏ anonymous coward

**with clear intent to**
❏ vandalize 
❏ plagiarize 
❏ revolutionize 
❏ editorialize 
❏ depersonalize 
❏ deglamorize 
❏ normalize 
❏ mordernize 
❏ deemphasize 
❏ harmonize 
❏ depolarize 
❏ decentralize 
❏ rationalize 
❏ reorganize 
❏ itemize 
❏ summarize 
❏ minimize 
❏ sterilize 
❏ downsize 
❏ satirize 
❏ penalize 
❏ resize 
❏ eulogize 
❏ publicize 
❏ criticize 
❏ oxidize 
❏ pulverize 
❏ suppress 
❏ repress 
❏ oppress 
❏ censor 
❏ pressure 
❏ displeasure 
❏ acupressure

**and I would like to**
❏ formally 
❏ politely 
❏ strongly 
❏ vibrantly 
❏ firmly 
❏ condemningly 
❏ definately 
❏ defiantly 
❏ definitely 
❏ defininantly 
❏ denfinantley 
❏ posthaste 
❏ temporarily 
❏ tentatively 
❏ lovingly 
❏ threateningly

**express my**
❏ surprise 
❏ disappointment 
❏ out- 
❏ rage 
❏ dismay 
❏ sorrow 
❏ letdown 
❏ befuddlement 
❏ discombobulation 
❏ displeasure 
❏ dissatisfaction 
❏ disenchantment 
❏ disillusionment 
❏ disenfranchising

**on/to**
❏ Facebook 
❏ YouTube 
❏ Twitter 
❏ Google+ 
❏ Reddit 
❏ 4chan 
❏ Tumblr 
❏ Discord 
❏ Medium 
❏ Killstagram 
❏ App.net 
❏ MySpace 
❏ Steam 
❏ HackerNews 
❏ LiveJournal 
❏ My Blog 
❏ Slashdot 
❏ Tindr 
❏ Use Perl 
❏ Ubuntu Discourse 
❏ IRC 
❏ Jabber 
❏ XMPP 
❏ Slack 
❏ Mattermost 
❏ Whatsapp 
❏ Telegram 
❏ chat.stackexchange.com 
❏ chat.stackoverflow.com 
❏ chat.meta.stackoverflow.com 
❏ meta.stackoverflow.com 
❏ meta.stackexchange.com 
❏ gaming.meta.stackexchange.com 
❏ gaming.stackexchange.com 
❏ the United Nations 
❏ Human Rights Watch 
❏ Congress 
❏ Conservapedia 
❏ Wikipedia 
❏ Uncyclopedia 
❏ Æncyclopædia Dramatica 
❏ Everything2 
❏ itch.io 
❏ TED 
❏ Instagram 
❏ Pinterest 
❏ Snapchat 
❏ Patreon 
❏ my belly 
❏ your *face*

**through the following immortal words of wisdom past:**

Ah! Now we see the violence inherent in the system! Come see the violence inherent in the system! Help! Help! I'm being repressed!

Does this company not care about freedom of speech?

Comment: Any and all references to members of this community past or present are purely coincidental.

Comment: -1 because I think serious topics need serious questions & titles. I also found the usage of ❏ to be obnoxious.

Comment: I'm not so much mocking cries of mod abuse as much as cries of freedom of speech and copyright-based claims. Everything the system allows is basically legal; we can then start discussing what's right and what's wrong, what should be done and what shouldn't.

Comment: block two is flawed, not all of the check boxes work in a sentence.

Comment: @Ender some knowledge of the English language required

Comment: @Badp further thoughts show me that if one can check 'any number' of boxes it still works, although clumsily

Comment: You **really** should read http://xkcd.com/1357

Comment: @Oded I'll try and work harder on my future reading skills!

Comment: @badp - On my side, I'll try to read comments on the answers first.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No.

Freedom of speech is an individual's limited freedom to publish his thoughts. It is not freedom to be published by anybody: the Wall Street Journal doesn't have to publish everything you send them, and neither does Stack Exchange.

In particular, the First Amendment to the U.S. Constitution is as follows:

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.

The government (or their agents) cannot restrict your free speech, but the First Amendment says nothing about corporations limiting free speech, because corporations cannot limit free speech.

Freedom of speech applies only to countries and similar entities who cannot prevent certain kinds of expression (with exceptions such as libel) from being expressed *at all.* Feel free to exercise your freedom of speech by publishing your speech on a piece of paper placed against your window or something. Depending on your ISP, you might also be able to run your own web site on your own pocket by using your own hardware and software you have a licence for.

Posts made on this site (or chat) are published on the site because you, the owner of the copyright, gave the site a licence to do so.

> You grant Stack Exchange the **perpetual and irrevocable right and license** to use, copy, cache, publish, display, **distribute, modify, create derivative works** and store such Subscriber Content and **to allow others to do so** in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, **even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You.**

http://stackexchange.com/legal

Of course Stack Exchange has the right not to exercise its licence, but if it does, it has the right to exercise it fully, including its right to publish derivative works. Your moral rights to your works of course remain valid; contact the team if you would like to anonymize your contributions. Your right to the integrity of your work is maintained by marking posts that have been edited as such (with exceptions such as question titles in lists thereof or chat messages on the list of starred messages), allowing you to audit its post history (with exceptions such as comments).

Comment: Your message is good but it is hidden behind a confusing title and a joke, when really it isn't a joke.

Comment: @res feel free to link directly to the answer. The question is there for our amusement only. :-D ...or trample my "freedom of speech" and just fix it yourself :-)

Comment: I like the question as it is, and would be very likely to revert it if it were heavily modified.

Comment: Please don't edit war.

Comment: I dont understand how the question and answer are related...

Comment: Question seems a little heavy-handed, but the answer is spot on

Comment: [XKCD is relevant, as always](http://xkcd.com/1357/).

Comment: @MBraedley This post predates XKCD by a few months, but yes, essentially that.

Comment: @badp I know, but it articulates the point so well I though it necessary to add.

Comment: Darn it @MBraedley, I was about to post that!

Comment: I hate this argument. "Freedom of speech" does not automatically mean the First Amendment in the United States. It is a concept that can be applied to _anything_. I have never, _ever_ heard anyone claim that their freedom of speech was being violated by a private site and therefore that site was breaking the law.