# </diamond> combo ×2

Tags: discussion, moderators

so this is a list of true statements:

- I have stopped hanging around on the main site
- I have stopped hanging around chat
- I have actually enjoyed from increased personal time in the last couple of months
- I have decided to spend the vast majority of it hanging out with local friends here in Amsterdam
- I received a friendly email warning me that this was cool but mods kinda need to be active and I was going to lose my diamond if I didn't do something about it
- I am okay with this

As I reread this, it's kinda shocking how self centered this post is, but that's kind of the point, isn't it?

So this is a post that, had I been honest with myself, I would have penned some three years ago. But I haven't been honest with myself, or you, and you deserve better.

The inflection point was definitely the moment when the mobile SO app stopped doing push notifications for meta questions. That stopped this community from being at the top of my mind, and allowed other things to fill up the void. These new things are not better or worse than my mod activity; they're just different, in a way I welcome.

I didn't coordinate with Ash, so I suppose this is an unexpectedly poignant time to say thank you for all of the fish, the stars, the mod abuse; thank you to those who helped me become a kinder person, those who merely tolerated me, and those who will be glad I'm "gone," and those who I'm not so glad they're "gone."

Doei!

Comment: Thanks for your 8 years of service. I'm disappointed at the lack of hyperlinks compared to your [nomination](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-15795).

Comment: @fredley I'mma write that up as a stylistic choice to respectfully distance myself from peak badp

Comment: Oh no, who is going to review my [mod abuse complaints?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7918/about-the-violence-inherent-in-stack-exchange-freedom-of-speech) :P Sad to see you go, but wish you the best

Comment: Remember when I used to have more rep than you? I member. `:P`

Answer (score 21):

It's been an honour serving with you kind sir, and hopefully all this getting outside more will help your complexion, because blue isn't a very healthy skin colour.

Comment: wait I said nothing about going outside

Comment: I tried going outside the other day.  I turned red.  I'm not sure that's a better color than blue from a health standpoint.

Answer (score 18):

I said it on [Ash](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13353/28182)'s post too, but to reiterate, I've always considered you as the kind of mod to aspire to: passionate, fair, knowledgeable, patient... just an all around good person.

It's been a pleasure moderating with you, thanks for everything, and all the best for what the future holds!